# How to print random hosts for each datacenters from the Map?

Tags: java, algorithm, random, dictionary

I am working on a project in which I have datacenters and host mappings.

Below is my map which contains datacenters and list of corresponding hosts mapping -

```
private static Map<String, List<String>> datacenterHostsMapping = new LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>>();
```

The above map contains the data like this -

```
{phx=[h0, h1, h2], slc=[h1, h0, h2], lvs=[h2, h0, h1]}
```

Here -

- `phx, slc, lvs` are the datacenters.
- `ho, h1, h2` are the hosts in that datacenters.
- Number of hosts in the datacenters will always be same and equal in number (here it is 3).
- And hosts can be in random order in each datacenters.
- And datacenters can be in random order as well.

Now I have a method which I will be calling at different point in our program and it will be using the above map in such a way such that for each datacenter, it should give me one random host but no hosts should be same with other datacenters.

```
private static void printRandomHost() {

    for(Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : datacenterHostsMapping.entrySet()) {
        // some code here?
    }
}
```

For example - If I am calling my above `printRandomHost` method for the first time, then it should give me this result like below. It can pick any random host in each datacenters but those hosts should not be same as compared with other datacenters - below is an example which it should print out -

```
phx - h0
slc - h1
lvs - h2
```

It can pick any random hosts for each datacenter, let's say it picked h0 for phx, h1 for slc, h2 for lvs. Here h0,h1,h2 are not same so this is fine. And it cannot print `h0 in phx, h0 in slc, h1 in lvs` as here h0 got printed out twice which is not what I want.

Now if I am calling my above method again, for the second time, then it should print out like this (again random hosts in each datacenters but this time, it won't print h0 for phx as it was already done for the first time and same with h1 for slc and h2 for lvs) so it should print out like this -

```
phx - h1
slc - h2
lvs - h0
```

And if I am calling my above method again, for the third time, then it should print out like this -

```
phx - h2
slc - h0
lvs - h1
```

And now it won't print out anything for the fourth time, because we completed all the hosts for each datacenters in the above three passes.

I hope the question is clear enough.. Now I am not sure how to incorporate this algorithm in my above method such that if I am calling for the first time, it should pick random host for each datacenter by making sure, not hosts are same.

Any help will be appreciated on this..

Comment: is there a way you can sort your hosts. If yes, that would make it simple.. something like phx[0],slc[1],lvs[2]

Comment: Some parts of your question do not make sense. How is the same host, say h0, available in 2 data centers ? Why does it matter which position you choose to display the random host if their order is random to begin with ? Thirdly, this API call has state. Is this a call to a web service of sorts ? Can you provide more context to the use case ?

Comment: @GV: Yes, we can sort the hosts as well. As it will always be h0, h1, h2, h3, h4, hn.. So we can sort it out basically..

Comment: Is the following situation illeagal? phx - h1
slc - h1
lvs - h1

Comment: @DeepakBala: I am working on Zookeeper schema, so each datacenters have three machines for now, but for the naming conventions, I have named it as h0, h1 and h2 for all the datacenters. It was an example, that host can be in random order or it cannot be as well.. This method will be running inside a rest service, and this method will be called for only one of our use case, so I know which methods in my rest service will be calling it..

Comment: @MouseLearnJava:yes it is illegal. hosts should not get repeated for each datacenter while printing out.

Comment: Well in that case it gets tricky. Looks like you need a [Restful](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/web.1111/e13734/stateful.htm) web service. You can also delegate state to another party (such as a database or redis) while still identifying who made the call (through a cookie or an auth param). Also think about how to reset this state since the client may return some other day asking for a random host.

Comment: @DeepakBala: Client is not going to ask anything.. It is one of my use case, that needs to call this method.. So if I am calling for the first time, it should give me first pass result, second time, second pass result, third time if it gets called, then third pass result, and fourth time if it gets called, then if possible fourth pass result otherwise nothing..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a try using the following code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class Example {
private static Map<String, List<String>> datacenterHostsMapping = new LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>>();

public static void main(String[] args) {

    datacenterHostsMapping.put("phx", Arrays.asList("h0","h1","h2"));
    datacenterHostsMapping.put("slc", Arrays.asList("h1","h0","h2"));
    datacenterHostsMapping.put("lvs", Arrays.asList("h2","h0","h1"));

    //Execute 5 times to print  data center and host information
    for(int i=1;i <=5;i++)
    {
        System.out.printf("Loop - %d \n", i);
        int index = 0;
        String[] randomHosts = generateRandomHosts(datacenterHostsMapping.get("phx"));
        for(String key :datacenterHostsMapping.keySet())
        {
            System.out.printf("%s - %s \n", key, randomHosts[index++] );
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}

   private static String[] generateRandomHosts(List<String> hostsList) {
    Collections.shuffle(hostsList);
    String[] randomHosts = new String[hostsList.size()];
    hostsList.toArray(randomHosts);
    return randomHosts;
}
}
```

Output in my example is as follows: 
*Note* - The output prints randomly, the result is changing in every code execution.

```
Loop - 1 
phx - h1 
slc - h2 
lvs - h0 

Loop - 2 
phx - h2 
slc - h0 
lvs - h1 

Loop - 3 
phx - h1 
slc - h0 
lvs - h2 

Loop - 4 
phx - h0 
slc - h2 
lvs - h1 

Loop - 5 
phx - h2 
slc - h0 
lvs - h1
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion and a great example but this is not what I am looking for in actual.. If you see your loop - 3 prints out, h1 for phx got repeated? right? And h1 for phx was already done in Loop - 1 so it should not be printing it out that loop and same with loop - 5 as h2 for phx was already done in Loop - 2..